# Threading waiting in java

Tags: java, multithreading

For examples I have 5 threads in total, the main thread (A) and 04 other sub threads (B,C,D,E). What I want is that the thread E will need to wait until thread B,C finish their works. I intend to use join(), but it seems that the main thread will be blocked also. I need the main thread and the thread D can continue running while thread E is waiting for thread B and C.

I don't know how can I implement this in a correct way. It would be great if someone can help.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Comment: You could use `FutureTask`

Comment: B,C,D,E are all launched from A?

Comment: yes B,C,D,E are launched from A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

**Class CountDownLatch**

```
java.lang.Object
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
```

---

```
public class CountDownLatch
extends Object
```

A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

**For example:**

Below is a completion signal that allows the driver to wait until all workers have completed -

```
    class Worker implements Runnable {
   private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
   private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
   Worker(CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
     this.startSignal = startSignal;
     this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
   }
   public void run() {
     try {
       startSignal.await();
       doWork();
       doneSignal.countDown();
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} // return;
   }

   void doWork() { ... }
 }
```

Comment: Why extend `Object` explicitly?

Comment: @MouseEvent - By default this class extends Object class to inherit its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Many possibilities such as [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), or you can put the `join()` calls into the `run()` method of Thread E.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can think is to pass an Object to Threads B, C and E and wait on it until both B and C are finished.

In Thread E you should have 2 wait lines:

```
lockObj.wait();
lockObj.wait();
```

And both Thread B and C should end with `lockObj.notify();`

I haven't tested this but in theory it should work.